# Kafka JDBC-Sink connector not working as intended

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I a trying to use the JDBC sink connector to put data into Postgres, however, I am not seeing any data created in my database. The connector config I am using it

```
{
  "name": "Test-Insert",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgres://<server_name>;databaseName=postgres;",
    "connection.user" : "username",
    "connection.password" : "password",
    "topics": "test",
    "name": "Test-Insert",
    "key.serializer":"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "auto.create":"true"
  }
}
```

the topic is one I have created in KSQL and I can see data on it.

Here is my log but I can not see anything that indicates

```
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,169] INFO Starting task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:43)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,172] INFO JdbcSinkConfig values:
        auto.create = true
        auto.evolve = false
        batch.size = 3000
        connection.password = [hidden]
        connection.url = jdbc:postgres://<ip>;databaseName=<db>;
        connection.user = <username>
        fields.whitelist = []
        insert.mode = insert
        max.retries = 10
        pk.fields = []
        pk.mode = none
        retry.backoff.ms = 3000
        table.name.format = ${topic}
 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkConfig:279)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,172] INFO Initializing writer using SQL dialect: GenericDialect (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:52)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,172] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=Test-Insert-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:282)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,168] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
        name = Test-Insert
        tasks.max = 1
        topics = [test]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig:279)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,176] INFO Setting task configurations for 1 workers. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector:45)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,170] INFO Loading template 'schema.namespace.format' (io.confluent.connect.cdc.SchemaGenerator:129)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,176] INFO Kafka version : 1.1.1-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:109)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,176] INFO Kafka commitId : 0a5db4d59ee15a47 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:110)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,176] INFO Loading template 'schema.key.name.format' (io.confluent.connect.cdc.SchemaGenerator:129)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,176] INFO Loading template 'schema.value.name.format' (io.confluent.connect.cdc.SchemaGenerator:129)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,177] INFO Loading template 'topicFormat.format' (io.confluent.connect.cdc.SchemaGenerator:129)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,177] INFO Starting Services (io.confluent.connect.cdc.BaseServiceTask:44)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,177] INFO Cluster ID: gi8ubA8UTEa4vzN5T6QDJw (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:265)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,178] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=connect-Test-Insert] Discovered group coordinator eu-west-2.compute.internal:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:605)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,179] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=connect-Test-Insert] Revoking previously assigned partitions [] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:411)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,179] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=connect-Test-Insert] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:442)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,182] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=connect-Test-Insert] Successfully joined group with generation 11 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:409)
[2018-07-25 14:16:55,182] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=connect-Test-Insert] Setting newly assigned partitions [test-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
```

Has anyone else come across this issue, or can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there's data in the `test` topic? Have you previously configured this connector? Maybe it's already read to the end of the topic and is waiting for new data? Changing the name of your connector will ensure it starts at the beginning of the topic.

Comment: Hi @ChrisMatta, yeah I'm sure there is data there, I ran my produce a couple of times to and I can see the data appear when I run `print test`. This is the first time I have configured the connector

Comment: you've produced to this topic _since_ you've started the connector? Are you sure the connector is in a good state? You can check the status with `curl connect-worker:8083/connectors/Test-Insert/status`